# Customizing Search box and button in O365

Tags: search, office-365

I want to customize the search box look and feel, I read an article about doing it using a delegate control, but that works only on prem, how do I do that in O365, I want to custom the textbox and make a custom button with some text on it like Search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to change the Search Box Control Template. Look in the Master Page Gallery/Display Templates/Search for the Control_SearchBox.html file. (Depending on the site template you may not have the HTML files. You may have to enable the Publishing feature.) Alternatively you can copy the HTML from another instance of SharePoint and copy it to this folder.

Comment: Hi Mathew, +1 for mentioning that, and that would let me change the whole look and feel for it? Another thing I had trouble with in the design, is that Microsoft is saying now with the design manager it's easier to put the html master page you had and SharePoint will convert it to master page for you. But that's not real, as all these controls that you have they are just static and you need to work on making SharePoint's control look like yours, am I right or mistaken?

Comment: I think it's safe to say that Microsoft underestimates the complexity of creating a functional master page. It takes someone how knows what the controls are and how they work to do a good job. I am not sure what you mean by "static". My firm regularly creates dynamic data driven master pages for our clients.

Comment: I mean once you convert your pure html to SharePoint html master page, it will only contain static html, which is your original html, it won't be dynamic, to make it dynamic you need then to get SharePoint controls and put them instead of your static html content, and work on that to make it look like the original design. It's not as straightforward as Microsoft makes it look like that in SP 2013 it's easier.

Comment: Correct, it's not as straight forward.